# Quickblox push notification failed

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, chat, quickblox

I am using Quickblox for chating application. Working on push notification for chat. I have uploaded APNs development certificate to Quickblox. I have done subscription via code and it shows my device in Quickblox admin section. But when i am trying to send push notification via admin panel, the push notification is not coming. I am choosing "Testing" environment and "IOS" channel and it shows:

```
"Success Apns channel. Notification has been successfully added to queue."
```

But notification wont come on device. In a queue section it shows:

```
APNS (Apple Push) Delivered: 0, failed: 1
Download detailed log
Event log
2016-03-21 06:50:34 UTC : queued 1 notifications
```

In detailed log it shows:

```
{"notification":{"aps":{"alert":"msg","sound":"default"}},"log":[{"device_token":"my token","created_at":"2016-03-23T04:48:04Z","delivered_at":null,"failed_at":"2016-03-23T04:48:51Z","error_code":8,"error_description":"Invalid token (8)"}]}
```

To register I am using this code :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSString *deviceIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    [QBRequest registerSubscriptionForDeviceToken:deviceToken uniqueDeviceIdentifier:deviceIdentifier
                                     successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, NSArray *subscriptions)
    {
        NSLog(@"Successfully Registered......");
    }
                                       errorBlock:^(QBError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error ------> %@", error);
                                     }];
}
```

And It shows "Successfully Registered......" And I can see it in admin section also.
Help me please..

Comment: What is an error stated in detailed log?

Comment: It shows "error_description":"Invalid token (8)". And sometimes it shows APNS (Apple Push) Delivered: 0, failed: 0 and in error log "error_description":"null". Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: does the same user is register for that device in the subscription section (Quickblox admin panel) in which you are sending the Push notification ? as old token may be changed or become invalid

Comment: Yes. The token shows in subscription section and token shows in detailed log both are same. @Pyro

Comment: Have you followed a complete guide here: http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-ios#Creating_APNS_certificates ?

Comment: Yes. I have added certificate, its showing my device there. I am first trying to test it from admin panel to check demo. But not working at all. Dont know whats wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Created new P12 certificate again with the new key and new development certificate. Then I got push notifications.